# jasmine: scope of this

Tags: javascript, testing

From the jasmine documentation (http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html):

> The this keyword
>
> Another way to share variables between a beforeEach, it, and afterEach is through the this keyword. Each spec’s beforeEach/it/afterEach has the this as the > same empty object that is set back to empty for the next spec’s beforeEach/it/afterEach.

My understanding of this in Javascript is, that this is bounded to the scope of the actual function. So I would expect that it would be bound to the context different contexts (the ones depending on the function) inside beforeEach/it/afterEach.

e.g.

```
describe('Spec', function (){
  var eachThis = null;
  beforeEach(function(){
    eachThis = this;
  });
  it('check this', function(){
    except(this).toEqual(eachThis);
  }
};
```

So this test should pass.

Did jasmine change the behavior of this or did i get something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your example maybe has some issues, but you are correct in thinking that jasmine manipulates the `this` reference when using `beforeEach`, `beforeAll`, etc.

Here is an illustrative example -- note that all of the expects listed below will pass:

```
(function() {
  describe("without beforeEach", function () {
    (function() {
      // this is not inside of a beforeEach call
      this.dog = "Spot";
      alert(this.dog);
    })();
    it("should not have access to a dog property from `this`", function () {
        expect(this.dog).toBeUndefined(); // because there is no `dog` member of the object currently referenced by `this`
    });
  });

  describe("a beforeEach test", function () { 
    beforeEach(function () {
        this.dog = "Spot";
    });
    it("should work now because we used `beforeEach`", function () { 
        expect(this.dog).toEqual("Spot");
    });

  });
})();
```

In general, your thinking about 'this' being defined within the scope of function is correct, but this implementation in jasmine demonstrates how you can provide a specific object to be referenced by the 'this' keyword if you want to. The typical way this is done in javascript is using `Function.prototype.apply()` which allows you to pass in an arbitrary object for the `this` reference as the first parameter of the function.

Comment: Thnx. I know the behavior of apply. The point is, that it's hidden here and the behavior looks more like traditional oop.

Comment: I would imagine the behavior is pointed out in the docs for precisely the reason you're suggesting (that it isn't obvious) -- I would most closely compare this to delegates in C# , but I'm sure there are other OO examples that are similar. I try not to make any assumptions about the knowledge of someone who asks a question here, I just think the discussion on apply is useful for the random person googling for info on the interwebs :)

Answer (score 0):

> So this test should pass.

Yes, and it does.

> Did jasmine change the behavior of this

It doesn't look like it.

> did i get something wrong

You have syntax errors and typos in your code (e.g. `except` -> `expect`).

---

Also, `toEqual` doesn't test the identity of an object, so even `expect(this).toEqual({});` would pass. `toBe` is a better method here.